# How can I set the Software Center to install software for non-root users?

Tags: software-center, software-installation, policykit

How can I set the Software Center to allow non-root users to install stuff from the Ubuntu repos without having to type in their password?

I'm fully aware of the security implications, and I am willing to take the risk. Fedora 12 shipped with something like this. (By modifying the PolicyKit configuration, I believe)

Comment: It's important to note that Fedora also backed it out after the sky fell down on them.

Comment: Yeah, I remember that. It really only makes sense on Desktop computers with only one or two users.

Comment: Bear in mind some app-market software like Software Center allows to change system repositories. A self-service of packages is risky, but users adding untrusted package sources is really dangerous.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can modify the PolicyKit permissions to allow the users to access the aptdaemon backend that Software Centre uses.

`dpkg --listfiles aptdaemon` shows that `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy` is the file specifying the actions possible on the aptdaemon backend.

Looking in that file, the `< action id="">` tags specify the possible actions.  You'd probably want `org.debian.apt.install-packages` to allow users to install new packages from the archive, and `org.debian.apt.update-cache` to allow users to update the package lists.

See `man pklocalauthority` which documents how to set local permissions on PolicyKit actions.  Putting the following into `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-allow-users-to-install.pkla` will allow any user logged in to the local machine to install packages after typing their own password (even when they're not in the admin group) and to update the package cache without typing any password.

```
[Untrusted Install]
Action=org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
ResultyAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=auth_self

[Untrusted Update]
Action=org.debian.apt.update-cache
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Kubuntu's policies (at least in Natty and Oneiric) are in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.kubuntu.qaptworker.policy`

Comment: Instructions for Kubuntu can be found in [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/3/6969#78806)

Comment: Life saver - cheers mate! I had to add `Identity=*` to get this to work, adapted from http://askubuntu.com/a/123260. Also, is there any way to get more policy kit log output in e.g. `/var/log/auth.log` (or any other log files) ? I only get `authentication fails` messages, but no reason why it failed...

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it's currently possible to do so via the GUI, but the following should work, albeit be a little kludgy. YMMV.

Add the following line to /etc/sudoers (use `sudo visudo` to edit the file):

```
%packageinstallers ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/software-center /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Then you just need to create and add the specific users to the `packageinstallers` group:

```
$ sudo addgroup packageinstallers
$ sudo adduser jdoe packageinstallers
```

Now `jdoe` can do the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install <some-package>
```

and you can edit the desktop menu item for the Software Center so that it call on `software-center` prepending the command with `gksudo`.

[PolicyKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PolicyKit) may allow you to do so without sudo, but it's beyond my understanding at this point.

Comment: Does this let them install from Synaptic or aptitude, or just apt-get?

Comment: If you were to add "/usr/bin/synaptic" to the list, it would. In fact, you could probably add "/usr/bin/software-center" to the list and it'd work. Haven't tested that though, let me know if it works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'll try that. :)

Comment: That would require that the users know to run software-centre with sudo, or for you to modify the .desktop file.

See my answer on how to tweak PolicyKit to do what you want.

Comment: Agreed, that'd be a superior solution.

Answer (score 5):

[RAOF's answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/258/6969) applies to Ubuntu only. Kubuntu uses QAptWorker as backend (observed for Natty and Oneiric). To allow for non-root installations, create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-allow-non-root-install-packages.pkla` containing:

```
[Update Software Sources]
Action=org.kubuntu.qaptworker.updateCache
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes

[Install Software]
Action=org.kubuntu.qaptworker.commitChanges
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=auth_self
```

I wanted to allow some non-admin users to install software while not granting sudo access directly. That was accomplished by inserting the next lines in both configuration groups:

```
Identity=unix-user:some-non-admin-user
```

If there is a group that must be granted permission, use `unix-group` instead of `unix-user`.

Comment: To re-apply the rules, I rebooted. (a re-login would probably work too)

Comment: How are you supposed to do this? Even after `sudo -i` I don't even have access to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` (Ubuntu 17.10): "Will not attempt to process directory /etc/polkit-1/localauthority"

Answer (score 5):

If you only need a generic permission to allow/disallow package installation, go for PolicyKit.

Unfortunately PolicyKit doesn't have fine control over the package to install. If you want to give your users permission to install only a restricted set of applications, you should use `sudo` and install something like softwarechannels...

I also looked for something like that, but since I didn't find anything, I coded this easy solution "softwarechannels", [available here on GitHub](https://github.com/alfem/softwarechannels)

It is a very simple system to allow common (non-admin) users to install packages from restricted catalogs.

Just define 'channels' (groups of packages) in a simple text file and give your users permissions to launch softwarechannels.

They will only see packages in channels matching their unix groups.

Answer (score 0):

To make this working in my Ubuntu 18.04, I had to change the /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-allow-users-to-install.pkla file to:

```
[Untrusted Install]
#Action=org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-*
ResultyAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=auth_self
Identity=*

[Untrusted Update]
Action=org.debian.apt.update-cache
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
Identity=*

[Admin Install]
#Action=org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-*
ResultyAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
Identity=unix-group:adm
```

Moreover with the last rule I enable everybody in the adm group to install/remove without any password.