# How can I let users in a particular group adjust CPU Frequency Scaling?

Tags: 10.04, policykit

I'm trying to let members of the group `labmembers` adjust the CPU frequency scaling on a system using `cpufreq-selector`. However, by default, this is restricted to members of the `admin` group.

Per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users), I've created the following file:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/30-site.d$ cat 50-cpufreq.pkla 
[CPU Frequency should be allowed for everyone]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:labmembers
Action=org.gnome.cpufreqselector
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=yes
```

However, it seems to have no effect. I can't find any command to reload PolicyKit's configuration, and rebooting doesn't do it either. I've also tried naming it `50-cpufreq.conf`, to no more effect. There's nothing I've found that would tell me whether a pkla file is well-formed or anything like that, either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that there's a typo in your configuration file. To restrict to a Group (or user) you'll need to use `Identity` rather than `AdminIdentities`

From the [pklocalauthority man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/pklocalauthority.8.html#toptoc4):

> ```
>    Identity
>       A semi-colon separated list of globs to match identities. Each glob should start with unix-user: or unix-group: to specify whether to match on a UNIX user name or a UNIX group name.
> ```

Ideally the syntax would be:

```
[CPU Frequency should be allowed for everyone]
Identity=unix-group:labmembers
Action=org.gnome.cpufreqselector
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=yes
```