# I want a non admin user to install software. What commands do I need to add to sudoers?

Tags: package-management, permissions, sudo, administration

I want to edit the /etc/sudoers file so that a non-admin user can install software via the Software Center in Linux Mint 10.  The reason for this is that I want a user to have the capability to install programs, but not make any other configuration changes to the system.

So far I have the following (some of these may not make sense, I was just trying whatever I thought of)

```
username ALL= /usr/bin/aptitude 
username ALL= /usr/bin/dpkg 
username ALL= /usr/local/bin/apt-get 
username ALL= /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/mintUpdate.py
username ALL= /usr/bin/software-center
username ALL= /usr/bin/synaptic
```

So far, it allows me to do updates without asking for my password, but it will not let me install software without entering an admin password.

I am aware of this question, [How can I set the Software Center to install software for non-root users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users), but this goes the route of modifying the PolicyKit, whereas I'm interested in a sudo solution, because it seems a simpler way to go.

Comment: If you read the answer/comments to that question that wasn't accepted, you'll see the problem with doing this through sudo. As software-center uses policykit to gain privileges, it is not actually run with sudo. Doing this with sudo would "would require that the users know to run software-centre with sudo, or for you to modify the .desktop file."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the Software Center to install software for non-root users?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users)

Comment: I see.  I tried the PolicyKit answer and it didn't work, but I will double-check my implementation.

Comment: "admin" and "non-admin" roles become very fuzzy when making modifications to enable this kind of thing.

Comment: FYI, So I did the PolicyKit solution, but I wasn't able to run the update applet in the task bar unless I had the mintUpdate line in my sudoers file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudo may be the more **simple** method, but PolicyKit is the more **secure** solution, afaik. You should go with the method outlined in the question you linked to.

Comment: Thanks.  That solution (http://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users/258#258) originally didn't work for me, but I looked in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy` to find the various "action id" entries that I needed.  Then, I looked at this link (http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/polkit/pklocalauthority.8.html#pklocalauthority-examples) to fine tune it.

Answer (score 6):

Note that giving users access to `dpkg` (or to a smaller extent any other package managers) effectively gives them complete root access. There is nothing stopping such a user from creating a totally new package with a setuid shell and installing it via `dpkg`, and then running that shell to gain full root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

If all only want them to be able to install programs you should be able to get by with only one program.  I might give them access to run `/usr/bin/apt-get install`.  If you aren't running automatic updates, then you may need to add `/usr/bin/apt-get update`.  To correct broken installs they may need `/user/bin/dpkg -C -a`.

Alternatively, you could enable synaptic, software-center, or aptitude.  Then you can point your users at the appropriate module.

Allowing users to uninstall packages could lead to functionality you consider being removed.