# How do I remove or inactivate certain options from the Lubuntu logout screen?

Tags: lubuntu, logout

The logout screen in Lubuntu 12.04 has several options. I'd like to remove or inactivate the "suspend" and "hibernate" options. Is that possible?

[image: logout screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I as know you cannot remove/change them (unless you edit the source code and recompile).

To disable suspend / hibernate, you can edit `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy`.

After this the suspend / hibernate are still in the Lubuntu logout window, but if you click them they do nothing (other than lock you out and you need to re-enter the password).

The content that need to be edited is between `<default>` and `</default>` for both **suspend** and **hibernate**: change (a) `<allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>` to `<allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>` and (b) `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>` to `<allow_active>no</allow_active>`.

It should be noted that these changes could be nullified by subsequent updates. A way to work around that is to set up a policy as described by the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/98006/25656).