# Disable authentication prompts in 15.04?

Tags: password, prompt, policykit

I'd like to know how I can disable the authentication prompts when opening apps such as Synaptic, mounting disks and so.

I got my user as passwordless set in sudoers, but seems the change to systemd changed something and now I keep getting prompted. Is there any way to set it like sudo in /etc/sudoers so my user can open such apps unprompted?

I am aware of the security risk, but this computer is not connected to the internet and no one else has access to it, I am aware of the safety risk, but I want to do this anyway, for convenience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent PolicyKit from asking for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98006/how-do-i-prevent-policykit-from-asking-for-a-password)

Comment: @DanielT I voted to leave this question open because I think it's a better question than the duplicate question that you linked to.

Comment: @karel The other one was older but if you want you could vote that one as a duplicate of this one

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I understand it, these prompts use Polkit, not `sudo`, for authorization. Therefore, setting `NOPASSWD` in `sudoers` won't make any difference to it. To make Polkit skip password prompts, create a `.pkla` file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` (say `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/99-nopassword.pkla`) containing:

```
[No password prompt]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=*
ResultActive=yes
```

See the [`pklocalauthority`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pklocalauthority.8) manpage for more information.

Comment: That's great, works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason created pkla file is not working on my system. I have polkit 0.105 and 18.04. How to debug what is wrong?

Comment: @Suncatcher afaik nothing significant has changed for Polkit in 18.04 (we're still well behind upstream 0.114 or the 0.112 release that include JavaScript rule definition support). Please post a new question with the exact filename and contents. You can leave a comment here when that's done, so I can take a look.

Comment: [created](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032687/polkit-pkla-rule-is-not-working-on-18-04), but on 18.04 I have old 0.105 polkit.

Comment: Is disabling policykit password prompts this way a security risk? On a system with a single admin user, can graphical applications take arbitrary actions?

Comment: @TravisG. no more or no less than a password-less `sudo`, I'd say.

Comment: @mru: there's a subtle difference with plain `sudo` though: with `sudo` you need to prepend it to `command` and thus you are reminded of the potentially dangerous effects, while Polkit seems to be "trusting" you know what you're doing. I didn't find a way to just a button with "are you sure?" or something to that effect; am I missing something?

Comment: As mentioned in a response to [this same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/123260/1085131). You can use `Identity=unix-user:scott` to only allow the user `scott` to do the action.

Comment: This does not seem to work on my freshly installed Ubuntu 22.4
Automatic login does not work and I get several prompts asking for my password when I log in.

Comment: @EnteFetz in that case, post a new question detailing the exact changes made, please

Comment: No luck for me in 22.04 ubuntu. echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/$USER this command will work for me