# How to disable the password prompts?

Tags: sudo, password, policykit

I've have Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop and just about everything I do requires me to enter my password.

What do I have to do so I don't have to keep entering my password?

Comment: Well, howdy Jim, pleasure to meetcha! Could you [edit] your question and show us a specific example of what you're trying to do which requires a password? Is this in the command line? In the pretty windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set my user account to have no password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password)

Comment: Well you can disable entering a password when using `sudo`, but as far as I know there is no way to get rid of say the Ubuntu Software Center asking you for a password.

Comment: @Zacharee1 see http://askubuntu.com/a/614537/158442

Answer (score 8):

To remove password prompts for commands/apps using sudo:

```
sudo adduser (your user name) sudo
sudo visudo
```

Change:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Exit `visudo`- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Run:

```
sudo service sudo restart
```

To remove password prompts for some graphical applications that use policy kit, not sudo see https://askubuntu.com/a/614537/115816.

Done. Bad idea, but there.

Comment: Not a full answer. This only gets rid of the password for `sudo`.

Comment: there is already comment to the question how to change policy kit settings...

Comment: But then you refer to that in your answer. Don't just answer part of it.

Comment: Polkit link added.

Comment: I have done this but it still prompts for password :,(