# How to disable all permissions and sudo password requirements?

Tags: sudo, security

I don't want it to ever complain about permissions or ask for sudo password ever again. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to say it is a really bad idea since it removes a big part of the security. To remove password prompts for commands/apps using sudo do

```
sudo visudo
```

to open the sudo file. Once in there change:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then exit and save using `Ctrl+x, y, Enter`

To remove password prompts for some graphical applications that use policy kit, not sudo do the following:
create a `.pkla` file in

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
```

for example the file could be named `99-nopassword.pkla` and the path would be

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/99-nopassword.pkla
```

That file should contain:

```
[No password prompt]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=*
ResultActive=yes
See the pklocalauthority manpage for more information.
```

Edit:

To completely remove the necessity of sudo for a terminal session, type `sudo -i` to execute your shell. After that you don't have to run sudo until you close that session

Sources:

[How to disable the password prompts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675379/how-to-disable-the-password-prompts)

[Disable authentication prompts in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614534/disable-authentication-prompts-in-15-04/614537#614537)

Comment: Thanks for answering. What about permissions though? If I do this, can I install anything without it complaining about permissions?

Comment: You still have to write sudo but it wont ask for a password. To completely remove sudo you'd have to switch to root user by typing `su root` but that's an idea even worse. If you know you have to type many commands in the terminal and don't want to write sudo every time you can also execute `sudo /bin/bash` to open an administrator shell in which you won't need sudo.

Comment: @Val9265 it's good idea to accept that answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @ADDB `sudo -i` gives a root login shell, right? Why use `sudo /bin/bash` then?

Comment: @takatakatek there's a slight different, that makes `sudo -i` preferable to `sudo /bin/bash`, because `sudo -i` runs the specific shell of the user's password entry, while `sudo /bin/bash` is only for that one shell.

Comment: @ADDB , So if I have specified `/bin/zsh` in `/etc/passwd` then `sudo -i` gives me *Zsh*, whereas `sudo /bin/bash` always gives *Bash*. Is that correct?

Comment: Right @takatakatek