# I can't install apps from Ubuntu software center after removing password!

Tags: password

Well , I know all the good reasons why I should protect my system with password , but I really want to keep using my PC without that popup window asking for password .
So I did some searches with DDG and followed some these instrutions:

1. Terminal commands: [explained in that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281085/614980)
   `sudo visudo` , editing that file by adding `NOPASSWD` in two lines.
2. Then , I followed that [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/281093/614980) to make my password empty.
   After that , I restarted my device but couldn't install any apps from Ubuntu Software centre !!

Comment: Did you do the __one more steps__ added  by @muru ? I think you missed that step!

Comment: Where is that step ?! @George

Comment: see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614534/disable-authentication-prompts-in-15-04/614537#614537)