# Require confirmation but not authentication before elevating

Tags: policykit

By default, many things that use polkit to  run (like synaptic) will ask the user to reauthenticate before starting. I'd like to disable this reauthentication, but still get confirmation that the user wanted to elevate. The closest thing I found is [Disable authentication prompts in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614534/disable-authentication-prompts-in-15-04), which disables authentication but doesn't provide a confirmation. Is it possible to make polkit ask for confirmation but not a password, like Windows UAC can do?