# Remove password protection 20.04

Tags: permissions, 20.04, password, security, desktop-environments

I am the only person who uses my PC.
Is there a way to disable the need to enter my password whenever I add a program, change settings, or sneeze? (my attempt at humour...sorry)

I understand laptop users on the go need it a lot more, but to a person like me, it's more of a pain. Plus 20.04 won't let me use my 4 digit pin.

I'd be happy hearing that plans for future releases might make it a built in option, rather than tweaking and possibly hurting something.

Thanks.

Comment: I have some computers that I'm not worried about, as I'm the only user. I disable the password requirement for 'sudo' in the terminal - because my workflow means I do quite a bit in the terminal. If you're mostly a GUI person, this won't benefit you much. I can tell you how to do that, if you want?

Comment: System security is not something that the Ubuntu developers are much interesting in watering down. It's one of the big reasons so many folks choose Ubuntu in the first place.

Comment: @ KGIII - Thanks, but no thanks for your offer, but yes, I'm a GUI guy. I'm also a (hopefully) former Microsoft Windows user.

Comment: @ user535733 - I understand 100%, and I agree with those of you who appreciate the tight security. I just wish there was a choice for those who feel they don't need it. That's all.

Comment: Could change password to a simple weak one like cont2, if present password is a good one.  One of the reasons for having a password is to make you think before installing something or run a command you really should not.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password

Comment: Not sure if [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614534/disable-authentication-prompts-in-15-04/614537#614537) still works.

Answer (score 1):

Even when you are the only person with access to that computer you should **not** disable this mechanism.

The main goal of asking for a password for "system" tasks (as crip659 stated in a comment) is to protect you from yourself by giving you a short moment to contemplate if you really want to do whatever is at hand.

- imagine some malicious link on a website
- a malicious macro in an office document
- a misplaced click on *delete* for some important system folder (like `/etc`)

Comment: ehm sorry this is not an answer to the question :P and https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password is already available

Comment: @ Rinzwind - I've already read that post before asking the question. It was the type of tweaking I was hoping to stay away from, plus it was for older versions of Ubuntu. Thanks though.

Comment: @ guntbert - No offence intended, but to me, slowing down to enter a password will very rarely prevent me from installing something. I do try to do my research before considering installing anything, then ask myself if I really want/need it. Most of the programs I install here are Ubuntu equivalents to Windows programs I've used for years anyways. Thanks for your concerns though.

Comment: @ crip659 - I originally tried using a 4 digit pin that I use for my laptop, tablet, and cell, but Ubuntu wants something more difficult. Thanks.

Comment: @ mikewhatever - Thanks, but that's the type of tweaking I'd like to stay away from.

Comment: -1 Instead of giving a solution, you give an explanation as to shy he shouldn't do it. You shouldn't have bothered answering.

Comment: Thanks for not answering the question. Will downvote as soon as I have enough reputation.