# Turning off all password prompts for specific user

Tags: software-installation, software-center, password, security, 21.04

I'm looking to turn off all password authentication prompts for a specific user (let's say Steve) on my Ubuntu 21.04 machine.

I added the line `steve ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` using `sudo visudo` and that removed the need to authenticate Steve's password when using sudo commands. However, I still get password authentication prompts when using GUI applications such as Ubuntu Software.

Is there a way to turn these prompts off just for Steve? I still want the other accounts to receive the prompts.

Comment: Possibly something like this: [How do I prevent PolicyKit from asking for a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98006/how-do-i-prevent-policykit-from-asking-for-a-password). You'd probably want `Identity=unix-user:steve` rather than `Identity=unix-group:admin`. Disclaimer - I haven't tried it.

Comment: @steeldriver That worked perfectly thanks for the help. Do you want to leave it as an answer so I can mark the question as closed?

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer since you've actually verified it - I was guessing about the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [steeldriver's](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) comment and [user55572's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/123260/491642) for this answer.

---

Replace `steve` with your own user name.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Run `sudo usermod -aG sudo steve`
3. Run `sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/disable-passwords.pkla`
4. Add

   ```
   [Do anything you want]
   Identity=unix-user:steve
   Action=*
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
5. Save the file and close