# How can I authenticate Ubuntu Software Center with user password?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, policykit

I would like to be able to use the password associated with this account to install packages with the GUI. Ideally, I would change the settings so that any user with sudo permissions could install packages. If that is not possible, I would like to be able to list all users that should be able to install. I know that this involves making changes to Policy Kit, and I have read [a page with a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users/258). However, I must need information specific to my own problem, because all my attempts so far have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, when you say 'this account', you mean your own one then you don't need to change anything because what you're describing is the default behavior. I've just set up a 'standard' account on my own system to check and it's working fine. If you want people to install with their own password you just need to give them administrative privileges.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I was not clear. The computer I am using is the legal property of a generous friend, so I always make an account for myself distinct from one I make for her. I wanted to be able to download software using my account's password.

And, yes, it turns out all I needed to do was make myself an administrator. Thank you much for your help!

Comment: @Veronika I recommend [accepting this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer), then.