# Standard user use software center

Tags: software-center

I have created a user and add him to the standard group. Now he cannot use software center, so I want him to stay in standard group but allow him to user software center. What is the best way to do that.

Comment: You will have to give him sudo permission to the user only for using the apt-get .

Comment: Yes, but sudo will allow him to do anything, it is same as making him administrator, but i only want him to use software center

Comment: Not necessary .... there is a file (i don't remember which) which gives permission to a specific user a sudo permission for a specific thing... I will let you know once I remember it!

Comment: Same question here with solutions proposed:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users

Answer (score -1):

You can specify commands, that are allowed for a user to be run as super user in `/etc/sudoers` file. Refer to manpage (`man sudoers`) for details.