# Hide "show wifi password" (don let show wifi password)

Tags: wireless, password

I've got to put a wifi password on my school laptops (all users are admin) but I don't want to the children see the password when you go edit conextions and edit de wifi like is see in the pictures. (I would like that you can't tick in the box Nº3, so only dots will be seen)
[image]

I would like sometihing like this that show key is like watermark so you can't see it and this screnshoot was taken in a admin acount (snox leopard osx (10.6.8) based with linux).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If founded with `$ sudo gedit /usr/share/nm-applet/ce-page-wifi-security.ui` and then you edit the line 55 and change True for False and in the network maneger it will appear like that.
[image]

Comment: Again, and I do not like repeating myself, how does that prevent any of those users to actually read this topic and go .... hey that is how I turn it back on, view the password, and set it back again?

Answer (score 2):

"(all users are admin)" there is your problem.

Even if you could hide it they, being admin, could always restore the settings, see the password and hide the setting again without you even knowing. What you want (hiding something from an admin) is never going to work.

The correct solution to your problem is to make those students users and elevate privileges to what you want them to do that requires then to even need admin privileges. Like installing software, updating etc. Here is an example using policyKit: [How can I set the Software Center to install software for non-root users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users)

Comment: The problem is that the laptops are owners of the children and they can do everthing, I wouldlike somting like osx wich it dosn't let you tick the box. I've add a picture of osx where "show the password" is in watermark and is an admin acoutn

Comment: Not going to happen. An admin in Linux can do anything. What you want are users with special privileges: the 2 basic things that require passwords are installing software and updating a system. If you let users modify /usr or /etc they -can- always reset what you did to remove the checkbox.

Comment: But probaly will be the option of change somthing of a preference document which the moste childre won't know, i probaly searching for that

Comment: - You underestimate your user base. - Security by obscurity has never worked.