# New admin account asking for a password?

Tags: password, administration

I've made new admin account. I did not set a password for that account and it now asks me for the password. Since I can access the account as it automatically logs on when the laptop is turned on, can I set a new password?

Comment: Linux is a known for its security. And password protection is first priority of linux. You always have to set password either you use it or not.

Comment: @Dishank Thats completely wrong. You can have accounts with no password even root.

Comment: But when you need to install new packages, you will face auth failed every time.

Comment: @Dishank Not if you configure [polkit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users/258#258)

Comment: Regardless, if you don't have a password on auth or admin - you're crazy.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a password from terminal, just open up your favorite terminal and type:

```
passwd
```

If your feeling advanced you can stop Ubuntu prompting for password by configuring `polkit`

Here's an example of [configuring polkit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users/258#258) to enable users to install apps without authentication.

Comment: Oh yes. I totally forget. Thanks mate. You made my Below answer totally wrong.

Comment: A much easier way to allow users to install apps without authentication (generally a bad idea) - is to run `sudo visudo` and add: `yourUser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get,/usr/bin/pip #etc`

Comment: @rm-vanda Your completely correct.  I'm guessing from the tone of the OP's question that they are not of the `sudo apt-get` kind but are using Ubuntu like a good old user and getting hit for GUI authentication.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forget those people exist. O_< -- wouldn't that trick work if the command were `/usr/bin/software-center` -?

Comment: @rm-vanda Yes, but user would have to still type `sudo /usr/bin/software-center`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can set password from there.

Restart your PC.

Go to recovery mode.

Press enter on prompt-shell

(command prompt will open with root access)

Type :- passwd (admin-name)

Then its all ok.

Comment: best answer because it's general -- works in a variety of situations.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, you may not understand what exactly an "admin" account is - 
My answer may be irrelevant, but it seems appropriate to leave it here, anyway.

For a user to be an "admin" - they have to be in the `sudo` group -

`$ sudo usermod -G sudo -a yourAdminUser`

and then `yourAdminUser` will be a *real* admin.

Comment: Simpler way: `sudo adduser yourAdminUser sudo`

Comment: That works if the user already exists?

Comment: yes. Given that user and group exists, `sudo adduser user group` adds user to group.