# How to install software using Software Center as non-root user?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, software-center, policykit

How can I allow non-root users to install from Software Center?

I want to be able to install software as current logged in user, but instead I am prompted with `Administrator` and `Password`.

This is close related to [Software Center to install software for non-root users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3/how-can-i-set-the-software-center-to-install-software-for-non-root-users), but the solution does not work.

I can confirm that it works when `Action=*`, but I do not want to give a non-adminstrator the ability to do whatever they like.